# Get external IP via email

Tags: python, networking, email, ip-address, raspberry-pi

I wrote a script for my Raspberry Pi that keeps checking my external IP. If it changes, the Raspberry Pi will send me the new IP via email.

Any suggestions for improvements?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os, time

def getIP():
        os.system('dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com > raspip.txt')
        with open('raspip.txt', 'r') as f:
                return f.readline().rstrip('\n')

def sendIP(currentIP):
        os.system('sendEmail '                            +
                  '-o tls=yes '                           +
                  '-f \'***@outlook.com\' '               +
                  '-t \'***@outlook.com\' '               +
                  '-s \'smtp.live.com\' '                 +
                  '-xu \'***@outlook.com\' '              +
                  '-xp \'**password**\' '                 +
                  '-u \"raspberry via python\" -m '       +
                  '\"' + currentIP + '\"')

def main():
        lastIP = None
        while (True):
                currentIP = getIP()
                if (lastIP != currentIP):
                        sendIP(currentIP)
                        lastIP = currentIP
                time.sleep(60)


if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: How set are you on using email? 1. DNS: If you manage your DNS and DHCP yourself, you can assign a hostname to your pi in the same way that a provider like no-ip does. This would obviously be local only, and if you absolutely need to use an IP, you could just do a quick dig. 2. Pushbullet: A quick bash script can send you the IP as a push to any of your other devices. [Pushbullet API documentation](http://docs.pushbullet.com/http/)

Answer (score 5):

You should probably prefer `#!/usr/bin/env python3` as it's less likely to vary on different systems. It's not a big deal, though.

You should use `snake_case`, even for `IP`, so names like `get_ip` and `send_ip`.

Don't call `os.system`; use `subprocess.Popen` instead:

```
subprocess.Popen('dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com > raspip.txt'.split())
```

```
subprocess.Popen([
    'sendEmail',
    '-o', 'tls=yes',
    '-f', '***@outlook.com',
    '-t', '***@outlook.com',
    '-s', 'smtp.live.com',
    '-xu', '***@outlook.com',
    '-xp', '**password**',
    '-u', 'raspberry via python', '-m',
    current_ip
])
```

This is safe against quoting errors (what if the IP contained `"`?).

You also didn't need the `+`s; strings automatically concatenate. You don't need to escape `'`s inside `""` or `"` inside `''` - but it doesn't matter with `Popen` since you don't need to worry about quoting.

You do:

```
with open('raspip.txt', 'r') as f:
        return f.readline().rstrip('\n')
```

It's more idiomatic to treat files as iterables, so instead one would do

```
with open('raspip.txt', 'r') as f:
        return next(f).rstrip('\n')
```

This also lets you add a default if wanted with `next(f, default)`. It might be a better idea to catch the error explicitly, since `StopIteration` can interfere with generators:

```
with open('raspip.txt', 'r') as f:
        try:
                return next(f).rstrip('\n')
        except StopIteration:
                raise ValueError("No text in raspip.txt!")
```

You also don't need the `'r'` argument - it's default.

Don't put brackets around conditions in loops of `if`s. It's just `while True:` and `if last_ip != current_ip`.

A more fancy example might use, say, Python's `email` library - but this is fine for what it does.

Answer (score 2):

Do away with file.

```
import subprocess as sp

def get_ip():
    return sp.getoutput('dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com').split()[0]
```